# Is there a way for Blazor to stop auto closing html tags?

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I'm trying to create some dynamic html with Blazor. Essentially I want a bootstrap(5.1) nav tab with a number of generated nav tabs created via a for loop

Code Below:

```
@:<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
@foreach(var tab in navTabs)
{
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="example" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#example" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="Example" aria-selected="true">Tab</button>
  </li>
}
@:</ul>
```

The ul tag on the first line seems to be auto closed so the li tags never get added to the nav tab.. I've also tried MarkupString.

Comment: Why is the @: there instead of e.g. not having it and having @foreach?

Comment: It won't compile if I remove the @: in front of them. If move it to the foreach it would create multiple nav tabs bars when i only want one, i  use the foreach to create the nav tabs in the nav tab bar...

Comment: I meant more like what Yiyi posted. Can you post a wider context? The ten lines above and below the markup you've posted, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 separate lines which break to HTML so the compiler will close the element.

```
@:@{
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    @foreach(var tab in navTabs)
    {
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="example" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#example" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="Example" aria-selected="true">Tab</button>
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
};
```

If your generating render fragments in the `@code` section why not just make them separate components you can conditionally use.

Comment: Excellent this solved it. Why does this solution work though?

Comment: @John-Michael Each line is treated as complete statement. The compiler would close the open element before it processes the next line. In my case there is a block enclosed  `{ ... }`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add `<ul></ul>` to html,and use `tab` as content of buttons.You can try this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
@foreach(var tab in navTabs)
{
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="example" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#example" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="Example" aria-selected="true">@tab</button>
  </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't compile in the razor component...

Comment: with what errror message ?